# how to insert data to database in another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am downloading data from server in AsyncTask and then I write it to database. Here is the part of doInBackground method:

```
DBConnection db = new DBConnection(context);    
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONObject cataloglist = json.getJSONObject("cataloglist");

                JSONArray array = cataloglist.names();
                db.clearNomenclature();
                for(int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++)
                {
                    JSONObject object = cataloglist.getJSONObject(array.getString(n));
                    db.insertNomenclature(object.getInt("version"), object.getString("name"), object.getString("uuid"), object.getString("measure"));
                }
```

here I access to the class DBConnection, in the method insertNomenclature of the DBConnection class I insert data to database as following:

```
        dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(context, "DB");
        database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+"nomenclature"+
                " ("+"ID"+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                "name TEXT, version INTEGER, measure UUID, uuid UUID)");

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("name", name);
                cv.put("version", version);
                cv.put("uuid", uuid);
                cv.put("measure", measure);
                database.insert("nomenclature", null, cv);
                database.close();
```

In logs I constantly get such messages:

```
12-12 12:11:40.825 26770-26770/com.example.sanzharaubakir.exgroup I/Choreographer: Skipped 4205 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I want database insertion to be executed in background but apparently it somehow works on UI thread. How can I move database insertion to another thread?

Comment: doInBackground is running on a separate thread, are you sure the frame skipping is caused by running it?

Comment: when I remove this line db.insertNomenclature(object.getInt("version"), object.getString("name"), object.getString("uuid"), object.getString("measure")); I don`t receive such message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand is you are trying to do a bulk insert, i would recommend the below approach for your case :

1) Create an arraylist of content operation before loop

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
```

2) In the for loop create contentoperation and add it to arraylist as below

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(COLUMN_NAME, VALUE);
 ContentProviderOperation operation = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ZoneConfigContract.ZoneInfo.CONTENT_URI).withValues(values).withYieldAllowed(true).build();
 ops.add(operation);
```

3) Then, at the end just apply the batch

```
getContentResolver().applyBatch(AUTHORITY, ops);
```

And yes you need to use content provider for this which i would recommend rather than writing sql queries for db operation.